# Почему не обрабатываются кнопки? Telebot

Tags: python, telebot

```
question = ' '
def get_question(message):
    global question;
    question = message.text;
    if question == '1':
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes');
        keyboard.add(key_yes);
        key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no');
        keyboard.add(key_no);
        question = 'С вашей карты снялись деньги?';
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Если в течение получаса на вашу почту не придет подтверждение, '
                                               'то пишите менеджеру: ');
    elif call.data == "no":
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup();
        key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes1');
        keyboard.add(key_yes);
        key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no1');
        keyboard.add(key_no);
        question = 'Проверьте мобильный банк и статус платежа. Статус «В ожидании оплаты»?';
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard

#не срабатывает этот метод, кнопки yes1 and no1 не обрабатываются.


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker1(call):
    if call.data == "yes1":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                         'Необходимо дождаться завершения оплаты. Если в течении часа не пройдет платеж, '
                         'то проверьте'
                         'исправность мобильного банка и напишите менеджеру: ');
    elif call.data == "no1":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Обращайтесь к менеджеру: ');


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, пишу бота на питоне и проблема с последним методом - кнопки не обрабатываются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут падает потому  что два обработчика callback_query_handler с одинаковым приоритетом и функцией-предикатом, применяемой ко всем входящим callback-запросам. Поэтому только первый обработчик будет срабатывать на все запросы + должны быть обработаны вторым обработчиком.

Можно исправить так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'yes' or call.data == 'no')
def callback_worker(call):
    # ...

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'yes1' or call.data == 'no1')
def callback_worker1(call):
    # ...
```